IDX10206: Unable to validate audience. The 'audiences' parameter is empty
I am trying to test that my .RequireAuthorization() are working in my custom minimal api endpoints by creating a JWT token from my CallingApi to the MinApi.
In my CallingApi, I am adding the generated token to the auth header.
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenGenerator.GenerateToken());
var url = $"https://localhost:7215/api/users";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

return Ok(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

The token generating code looks like this:
public static String GenerateToken()
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CallMinApiKey-ThisNeedsToBePrettyLong");

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestUser")
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        Issuer = "TestIssuer",
        Audience = "TestAudience",
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}

When I was calling my MinApi, I was getting a 401 status code.  To get what the reason was, I added a token validation method in my CallingApi, which looks like this:
public static String GenerateToken()
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CallMinApiKey-ThisNeedsToBePrettyLong");

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestUser")
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        Issuer = "TestIssuer",
        Audience = "TestAudience",
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

    var testTokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    TestValidateToken(testTokenString);

    return testTokenString;
}

public static Boolean TestValidateToken(String testTokenString)
{
    var token = testTokenString;
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CallMinApiKey-ThisNeedsToBePrettyLong");

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "TestIssuer",
        ValidAudience = "TestAudience",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };

    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Token is valid.");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unknown error: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return false;
}

Each time, validation throws an exception and the message is: IDX10206: Unable to validate audience. The 'audiences' parameter is empty.
But, I put my token in jwt.io and it has an "aud" value see:
my token parsed on jwt.io
-- Update
Here's the auth setup in my MinApi's Program.cs.
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CallMinApiKey-ThisNeedsToBePrettyLong");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "TestIssuer",
        ValidAudience = "TestAudience",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

What am I doing incorrectly?

Try the parse method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue?view=net-8.0#methods

I'm not sure how this would work. If I just parse the returned token, I wouldn't be setting the schema. How is this the correct way and why would the way I have it not work?

The issue is with the following : ttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenGenerator.GenerateToken());  AuthenticationHeaderValue is a class object which takes two string parameters in the constructor.  I'm not quite sure what the 2nd string is suppose to be from the websites.  I do not think it is the string value you are using or not all the parameters in the class are getting set properly.  I think the parse method will set all the parameters correctly.

I attempted httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(TokenGenerator.GenerateToken());, but still get a 401.

Are you still getting IDX10206: Unable to validate audience. The 'audiences' parameter is empty.

Yes, but just to clarify, the error message that I'm getting is coming from the TokenGenerator.TestValidateToken that is called each time a token is generated. I updated my question with my MinApi's auth setup. I just get a 401 Unauthorized when I call the MinApi with no details.  That's why I added the TestValidateToken to try to get more info.

Try setting to false and see if you get any other errors.  It may no be the audience that is the real issue : ValidateAudience = false,

Powershell is written in Net Library.  So following link may help you find issue.  The PS code is really c#code : https://sapling.ai/programming-languages/jwt/powershell

I set ValidateAudience = false in both the TestValidateToken and in the MinApi auth settings, the TestValidateToken returned true (without exception), but the MinApi still returned 401.  I will attempt using the powershell code.

I attempted using the powershell code, I still got a 401 with it as well.  I even tried setting ValidateIssuer = false, ValidateAudience = false, ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false in the MinApi and still get 401.

Did you try the PS code?  Error 401 (not authorize) means the token (credentials) are not valid for the data you are trying to obtain at the server.  The solution is to use a different user account to create the token that has access to the server, or modify the server credentials to accept the user account associated with the token.

Yeah, I tried the PS code as well.  I still got 401 returned.

The issue is that you're validating the token with the JwtSecurityTokenHandler instead of with the JsonWebTokenHandler. I just spent several hours banging my head against the wall with this same issue, before stumbling across https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events which led me to discovering the problem.

Thank you for the tip! This saved me a lot of time
